# Use regex to contextually replace dots in a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all occurrences of dots separated by single characters, I **also** want to replace all occurrences of dots separated by more than one consecutive character with a space (if one side has len > 1 char).

For example. Given a string,

`s = ' A.B.C.D.E. FGH.IJ K.L.M.NO PQ.R.S T.U.VWXYZ'`

After processing the output should look like:

`'ABCDE FGH IJ KLM NO PQ RS TU VWXYZ'`

- Notice that in the case of `A.B.C.D.E.`, all dots are removed (this should be true for when there is no trailing dot also)
- Notice that in the case of `K.L.M.NO`, the first two dots are removed, the last one is replaced with a space (because NO is not a single character)
- Notice that in the case of `PQ.R.S`, the first dot is replaced with a space, the second dot is removed.

I *almost* have a working solution:

`re.sub(r'(?<!\w)([A-Z])\.', r'\1', s)`

But in the example given, `T.U.VWXYZ` gets translated to `TUVWXYZ`, whereas it should be `TU VWXYZ`

Note: it's **not** important for this to be solved with a single regex, or even regex at all for that matter.

Edit: changed `PQ.RS` to `PQ.R.S` in the example string.

Comment: Are you ok with non-regex solution?

Comment: yep it doesn't have to be regex necessarily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take two steps.

1. replace `(\b[A-Z])\.(?=[A-Z]\b|\s|$)` with `r'\1'`
2. replace `(\b[A-Z]{2,})\.(?=[A-Z])|(\b[A-Z])\.(?=[A-Z]{2,})` with `r'\1\2 '`

Sample

import re

```
re1 = re.compile(r'(\b[A-Z])\.(?=[A-Z]\b|\s|$)')
re2 = re.compile(r'(\b[A-Z]{2,})\.(?=[A-Z])|(\b[A-Z])\.(?=[A-Z]{2,})')

s = ' A.B.C.D.E. FGH.IJ K.L.M.NO PQ.RS T.U.VWXYZ'

r = re2.sub(r'\1\2 ', re1.sub(r'\1', s)).strip()
print(r)
```

outputs

```
'ABCDE FGH IJ KLM NO PQ RS TU VWXYZ'
```

which matches your desired result:

```
'ABCDE FGH IJ KLM NO PQ RS TU VWXYZ'
```

- `re1` matches all dots that are preceded by a free-standing letter and followed by either another free-standing letter, or whitespace, or the end of the string.
- `re2` matches all dots that are preceded by a least 2 and followed by at least 1 letter (or the other way around)

Answer (score 1):

You can first replace all dots followed by two characters by spaces, and then remove the remaining dots:

```
re.sub(r'\.([A-Z]{2})', r' \1', s).replace(".", "")
```

This gives `" ABCDE FGH IJ KLM NO PQ RS TU VWXYZ"` on your example.

Comment: Many thanks! Though I believe this would break for the case `s = ' PQ.R.S`, which would give `PQRS` instead of the expected `PQ RS`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your rules are, but you can for example do a second pass (before removing the dots) with `re.sub(r'([A-Z]{2})\.', r' \1 ', s)`, which replaces dots preceded by two characters by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this is slightly neater:

```
import re

s = ' A.B.C.D.E. FGH.IJ K.L.M.NO PQ.RS T.U.VWXYZ'

s = re.sub(r"\.(\w{2})", r" \1", s)
s = re.sub(r"(\w{2})\.(\w)", r"\1 \2", s)
s = re.sub(r"\.", "",s)
s = s.strip()
print(s)
```

Comment: Many thanks! Though I believe this would break for the case `s = ' PQ.R.S`, which would give `PQRS` instead of the expected `PQ RS`. I updated the example to include this case.

Comment: just noticed your reply on the other answer.  was not obvious from your question.  updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single regex solution if you consider using a dynamic replacement:

```py
import re
rx = r'\b([A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])+\b(?:\.(?![A-Z]))?)|\.'
s = ' A.B.C.D.E. FGH.IJ K.L.M.NO PQ.R.S T.U.VWXYZ'
print( re.sub(rx, lambda x: x.group(1).replace('.', '') if x.group(1) else ' ', s.strip()) )
# => ABCDE FGH IJ KLM NO PQ RS TU VWXYZ
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EmKXiE) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f3EWB7/2).

The regex matches:

- `\b([A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])+\b(?:\.(?![A-Z]))?)` - a word boundary, then Group 1 (that will be replaced with itself after stripping off all periods) capturing:

  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `(?:\.[A-Z])+` - zero or more sequences of a dot and an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `(?:\.(?![A-Z]))?` - an optional sequence of `.` that is not followed with an uppercase ASCII letter
- `|` - or
- `\.` - a `.` in any other context (it will be replaced with a space).

The `lambda x: x.group(1).replace('.', '') if x.group(1) else ' '` replacement means that if Group 1 matches, the replacement string is Group 1 value without dots, and if Group 1 does not match the replacement is a single regular space.